# instead of 404 error, redirect to other site using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We've moved a site to another domain and setup the htacess as bellow, but how can i set a rule "if page dosnt exist - (ie 404 error) redirect to new site homepage." To be used as a fall back, if someone follows a broke url to our old site.

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.oldsite\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://oldsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk http://newsite.co.uk
Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk/index.html http://newsite.co.uk

Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk/contact-us.html http://newsite.co.uk/contact-us.html
Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk/bespoke-furniture.html http://http://newsite.co.uk/bespoke-furniture.html
Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk/about-us.html http://newsite.co.uk/about-us.html   
Redirect permanent http://oldsite.co.uk/how.html http://newsite.co.uk/about-us.html


order deny,allow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *simply* use this.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://newsite.co.uk
```